# Count missing rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a long excel list (+10k rows) and a column with ordernumbers.
Unfortunatelly some orders were deleted.

My question is simple but to achieve probabily not: I want to count the deleted rows, basically the missing ordernumbers.

A hint is aprechiated.
endo

Comment: Are these strictly numeric values, like "1053" and "2", but not mixed values like "105-A", etc.?

Comment: Also, are you trying to identify the missing numbers? Or just count them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now count blanks in Excel with a simple function called `COUNTBLANK`. If you know the ending row number (for example, if the data were in `A1` to `A10000`), you can use this formula:

```
=COUNTBLANK(A1:A10000)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this using Excel code, but if you go to the bottom and get the last order number, you can calculate how many there should be with

```
last order number - first order number = expected amount
```

How many their actually are would be

```
last order index - first order index = actual amount
```

Then you can do

```
expected amount - actual amount = missing order numbers
```

Of course, this assumes there are no blank rows between order numbers, and that you only need to do this once. (you prob want a function or something to have it update as you change the spreadsheet)

Answer (score 3):

This covers blank rows and numbers missing from the sequence (however, if your min/max are deleted, this can't detect that). It's similar to @shieldgenerator7's answer.

No sorting necessary for this.

EDIT: As sheildgenerator7 pointed out, this assumes that you expect all of your order numbers to be sequential.

`=(MAX(A2:A26)-MIN(A2:A26)+1)-COUNTA(A2:A26)`

[image]

Comment: this also assumes that the numbers are supposed to be sequential

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 that's true, thanks for pointing that out. I'll update the answer. Also, now that we're in 2021, I added a new answer which is much easier now that Excel has the `COUNTBLANK` function. It doesn't require the numbers to be sequential.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers are sequential it is pretty easy.

Sort by order number

Count in B4

```
=(A4-A3)-1
```

Sum in B17

```
=SUM(B3:B16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I put together to identify missing numbers and optionally print the list out on a new workbook.

You can change the minimum and maximum number, and it does not matter if the list is sorted or not.

```
Sub FindMissingNumbers()
    Dim lstRange As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim lowestNumber As Long
    Dim highestNumber As Long
    Dim missingNumbers() As Variant
    Dim m As Long
    Dim wbNew As Workbook

    '## Set this value to the lowest expected value in ordernumber'
    lowestNumber = 0
    '## Set this value to your highest expected value in ordernumber'
    highestNumber = 100

    'Assuming the order# are in column A, modify as needed:'
    Set lstRange = Range("A1", Range("A1048576").End(xlUp))

        For r = lowestNumber To highestNumber
            '## Check to see if this number exists in the lstRange
            If IsError(Application.Match(r, lstRange, False)) Then
                '## Add this number to an array variable:'
                ReDim Preserve missingNumbers(m)
                missingNumbers(m) = r
                m = m + 1
            End If
        Next

        If MsgBox("There were " & m & " missing order numbers" _
            & vbNewLine & "Do you want to print these numbers?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
             Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
                With wbNew.Sheets(1)
                   ' For r = LBound(missingNumbers) To UBound(missingNumbers)
                   ' .Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = missingNumbers(r)
                   ' Next
                    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(missingNumbers) + 1) = _
                         Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(missingNumbers)
                End With

        Else:

        End If

End Sub
```